# Spring roo deleting all .aj files upon opening the console in source directory

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-roo

This is with respect to an existing roo project. I imported it as a maven project in STS, changed the Java version to 7 from 6 , updated maven it runs neatly. No issues with that .

But now I tried opening the roo console in the source directory and boom

it just starts deleting all the .aj files without me trigerring anything.

This is how the sequence goes.

Deleted /*/*/*that_*.aj - not required for governor 
or else it just says it is empty and all the previously generated .aj files gets deleted. Now when I close the shell and try reopening it hoping roo to generate the files. That does not happen at all.

Any help on this will be highly appreciated. I am new to spring roo

and also it is configured to use  2.0.0.M1  but I am using m2 version and I am guessing that is not the issue here.

Answer (score 1):

Roo 2.0 will contain API changes and less add-ons than previous version so this release won't be backward compatible with the version 1.3 (https://spring.io/blog/2015/03/30/looking-ahead-to-spring-roo-2-0)

So, those API changes are being done in each milestone, whom could be incompatible between them.

If you started the project with Roo 2.0.0.M1 you should continue using that version.

Good luck,

Comment: ok i see that the project is configured with roo 2.0.0.M1 i use 2.0.0.M2 in sts is that a problem? and why does it go on deleting all the generated aj files without me triggering anything other than opening the roo shell in the project. The moment I open i see a lot of errors in the project

Comment: It's a normal behaviour, Roo regenerates the .aj files, the problem is that the M1 defines metainfo that has changed in the M2, so, Roo deletes the .aj files but it doesn't understand the metainfo generated by M1,  so, it doesn't generate the .aj files again.